# Does Chrome support "display: block grid"?

Tags: css, google-chrome, display

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/display), it is possible to set both block and grid values at the same time on the CSS display property (ie. `display: block grid;`).

However, when I try on Chrome, Chrome doesn't seem to accept this syntax.

[image: Chrome doesn't accept "display: block grid"]

When I try on Firefox, on the other end in the same context, it works just fine.

Is this an issue with Chrome's implementation or am I missing something?

Comment: The [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#browser_compatibility) on the linked MDN page says no

Comment: Here specifically: [More Direct Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#browser_compatibility)

Comment: To the two above me: both links are the same; somehow I got stuck at the top, even with the anchor. Here's another link to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_display_multi-keyword_values), which shows that only FF 70+ (2019) and Safari 15+ (2021) support this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser feature to look for is "multi keyword values", thanks!

And [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_display_multi-keyword_values) does state the fact that Chrome does not support the feature.

[image: canIuse screenshot]